# NY Times Word Cloud Portrait

Tags: algorithm

Recently, NY times created an app that produces images of peoples faces using a word cloud. I'm looking for some insight into the fitting / nesting algorithm that could do this. If anyone has any info I'd much appreciate it.

here's one of the images it produced:
http://blog.jackmorton.com/image/40203148057

If you want to see any more just google 'ny times word cloud portrait'

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, a couple of things recommended here. Firstly, to get the valid blobs for word placement I would suggest using SKimage with some histogram normalization on the image of the picture you'd like to do this on.

As far as the fitting and nesting algorithm go, firstly I'm willing to bet that this wasn't actually made algorithmically, but assuming that it was, here's how I would approach it, assuming you already have your corpus and a way to evaluate the size of rendered words, which it kind of crucial to this problem.

1. Calculate total word size over some packing efficiency. Compare this to total area in blobs returned by the histogram normalization of your original image.
2. Reduce your base size until the word size/packing efficiency is less than the total space you have available.
3. The following should be done iteratively/recursively depending on your style:

   - Take your largest word, and place it in a blob that is large enough to hold it, ensuring that at least two corners of the word box are on edges of the blob. Should also ensure that at least x% of the word box is within the blob, but that step isn't as important
   - Replace the wordbox you just placed in your image with a white box in the previous image, meaning it's no longer allocated for new word placement
   - If at any point there are no blobs large enough for your largest word, reduce the size of all words and boxes present until there is enough room and continue, or if you've already placed enough just call it a day.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not concerned with that. It's to be a Flash app, so I'll get a pic from a webcam, and then I can threshold, contrast, etc. the image to get what I need as far as black/white areas. Although you say 'valid blobs' and just post-processing the image likely won't produce those. Still, for now I am concerned with the text fitting algorithm.

Comment: Why on earth are you making this a flash app? Are you from the 90s? WebRTC is established and fast and the number of platforms supporting flash is dwindling by the day. And post-processing the image is the only way to produce valid blobs unless you misunderstand post-processing. What you really want to do is intelligently edit a fourier transform of the image. If you want to know about that then ask another question and I can post more there.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite helpful. Why do you bet their version isn't algorithmic? How else might they have done it?

Comment: I would bet it's not algorithmic since it's the New York Times, much more likely to have an artist doing it than have a programmer write it. It's pretty easy to have an artist drag and drop appropriately sized words which is how many things like this are done.

Comment: Also, don't forget to upvote/accept if an answer is helpful to you, which you should also do for the firefox svg question.

Comment: You don't do Flash, that's fine - but you're also quite wrong about it. it's alive and well, and can do everything I need.

Comment: Oh, I see why you said it's not algorithmic... it is then. It's a live app they have at trade shows.

Comment: Ah, that's pretty cool! Also, any language can do everything you need (See: Turing Completeness), but in the community at large flash and actionscript really are quickly going out of style and if you're planning on going ahead for many years longer, devoting your time to learning those technologies is probably less useful than learning WebRTC. http://ntt.cc/2010/07/01/java-back-at-number-1-actionscript-number-22-tiobe-programming-community-index-2010.html and http://www.langpop.com/ if you don't believe me.